# What happens if the interpreter specified after #! is not available?

Tags: linux, shell, shebang

What happens if the interpreter specified after `#!` is not available?

I know that after the shebang I have to specify the interpreter (best practice is `/bin/bash`). As a beginner I don't dare to try a lot I am afraid to damage my system.

Could you give me examples of screenshots of the two scenarios:

- the interpreter exists
- the interpreter is not available

I just want to understand.

Comment: Give it a shot. You won't damage anything, promise.

Comment: Ok thank you. So I will first try with an interpreter available but how could I know which interpreter is not available in my system... Sorry I am a real beginner :)

Comment: Sure, type some garbage. `#!/foo/bar` or `#!blahdeblah` or whatever.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try :)

Comment: I have tried this `#!/foo/bar`

Comment: I got this    `'#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. `

Comment: Did you write that on the command line or did you put it in a file that you made executable via `chmod +x thefile`?

Comment: Are you sure you are on linux?

Comment: I wrote it in the command line directly

Comment: That error looks like one on Windows platform. Are you sure you are on linux ?

Comment: There's no best practice for what to use as the shebang. Use whatever path you need to execute the correct interpreter. (Note this means the *installer* is in the best position to choose which path to use, not the author of the script.)

Comment: I tried it in WSL Ubuntu. I just created a file `shebang-test` with one line: `#!/foo/bar`, then ran `chmod +x shebang-test` to make it executable and finally ran it using `./shebang-test`. The output was: `-bash: ./shebang-test: /foo/bar: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Try `#!/usr/bin/env interpreter` where `interpreter` is the name of the interpreter you want to use. The command `env` searches `PATH` for the command (`interpreter`) and runs it.

Comment: @md2perpe So does that mean that the file shebang test was unavailable (but you created it) or the content of the file that creates the error message ?

Comment: "bad interpreter" means that the program on the `#!` line can't be run for some reason. In this case, it's because it doesn't exist.

Comment: The interpreter that I specified after the shebang was unavailable and the operating system (bash or Linux) gave an error message.

Answer (score 3):

> try a lot I am afraid to damage my system.

Don't worry - it's safe here. Programmers make typos all the time.

> the interpreter exists

For example, a file named `thefile` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/cat
blabla
```

Then, when the file has [executable permission bit set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Permissions), then [executing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) the file itself will execute the program `/bin/cat` with one argument `./thefile`, as if you would type `/bin/cat ./thefile` in your shell. [Program `cat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) just prints the content of the file, so when exeucting `./thefile` will execute `/bin/cat ./thefile` with will print the file content to the screen.

```
$ ./thefile 
#!/bin/cat
blabla
```

> the interpreter is not available

> What happens if the interpreter specified after #! is not available?

If the shebang happens to be interpreted by your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)), it would be expected that your shell will then print some kind of an information message that it can't find the interpreter, with some error description that "this file does not exist" or similar. If the file is run via [one of `exec*()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) [system calls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), then the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) will return with [`ENOEXEC`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) [error code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) (per [source code here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_script.c#L59))

Let's take a file named `anotherfile` with the following content:

```
#!fdsafdsafafdasfdas
blabla
```

For example, [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) shell [will try to parse `#!` line](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/15409324f1974d41c183904ad575da7188058c1c/execute_cmd.c#L5866) by itself. Bash interactive shell would print:

```
$ ./anotherfile 
bash: ./anotherfile: fdsafdsafafdasfdas: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

But, for example, Busybox's [Ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) shell [presents a different message](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/shell/ash.c#L7762):

```
$ ./anotherfile 
/bin/sh: ./anotherfile: not found
```

Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) might be interesting.